# Nested promises Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

So basically i have a program that merges data on the server side.
This is a sort of a simulation (in this case the resturn is always true) and i am looping through 2 array object in javascript 1 of length 10 and 1 of length 5 as shown.

My aim is that for every outerpromise 5 inner promises are required to move to the next outer promise.

Here is the code:

```
var OuterPromises = range(1, 10);
var InnerPromises = range(1, 5);

$('.--btn-start-promising').click(function() {
    var _outerPromise = Promise.resolve();
    var OuterPromisesCompleted = 0;
    OuterPromises.forEach(OuterPromise =>
    _outerPromise = _outerPromise.then(() => CallOuterPromise(OuterPromise)
        // .complete(result => {
        //     OuterPromisesCompleted++;
        //     $('.--outer-promise-completed').text(OuterPromisesCompleted);
        // })
        .catch(error => {})));
})

function CallOuterPromise(promise)
{
    var _innerPromise = Promise.resolve();
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php/merger/outerpromise',
        success: function() {
            var InnerPromisesCompleted = 0;
            InnerPromises.forEach(InnerPromise =>
            _innerPromise = _innerPromise.then(() => CallInnerPromise(InnerPromise)
                // .complete(result => {
                //     InnerPromisesCompleted++;
                //     $('.--inner-promise-completed').text(InnerPromisesCompleted);
                // })
                .catch(error => {})))
        }
    })
}

function CallInnerPromise(promise)
{
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/index.php/merger/innerpromise',
        success: function() {

        }
    })
}

function range(min, max){
    const arr = Array(max - min + 1)
        .fill(0)
        .map((_, i) => i + min);
    return arr;
}

function SysOut(...args)
{
    $.each(args, function(i, a) {
        console.log(a);
})
}
```

Promises work, the problem here is that the sequence of it happening is not correct and moreover some inner promises do not happen.

The execution sequence is as follows Outer->Inner->Outer for the first nine outer promises and then for the last outer all other 5 inner promises happen.

The sequence i want to achieve is as follows:

- Outer 1

  - Inner 1
  - Inner 2
  - Inner 3
  - Inner 4
  - Inner 5
- Outer 2

.. and so on
Basically all requests are 1 by 1, when an outer is complete the inner start 1 by 1 than when ready the next outer is processed and so on.

What am i doing wrong?

On another note.
As you may notice there is a complete commented. which when used it says undefined. What is the method to know it was completed and update my UI?

Regards.

Comment: you aren't chaining properly  - don't use the `success` callback if you want to deal with the jquery Promise as you are ... something like `return $.ajax(....).then(()=> Promise.all(InnerPromises.map( x => InnerPromise(x))`

Comment: Can you please give me an example on my code.

Comment: sure `function CallOuterPromise(promise) {
    return $.ajax('/index.php/merger/outerpromise').then(() => Promise.all(InnerPromises.map(InnerPromise => CallInnerPromise(InnerPromise))))
}`

Comment: will this make the inner promises one by one or all at the same time? Sorry i am really new to promises. And additionally the inner promises are a result of the outerpromise result how can i use it?

Comment: Promise.all makes it parallel - you use it by using `.then` as with every promise

Comment: Then promise all is not good for me since i need all promises to be done by one even the inner promise. :/

Comment: then use a for loop with async/await

Comment: I tried here but still no success here is my other post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458305/jquery-nested-ajax-foreach-await-async   this thing is driving me crazy :/